# Parsing JSON objects to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to parse a JSON object into an html table however I can't seem to get it right.

DESIRED FORMAT:

```
Last Year     This Year     Future Years
45423         36721         873409
```

CURRENT FORMAT:

```
Last Year     45423
This Year     36721
Future Years  873409
```

JSON:

```
[{column_name:"Last Year", "column_data":45423},{column_name:"This Year", "column_data":36721},{column_name:"Future Years", "column_data":873409}]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="main-aged-debtors-bar" style="height: 250px"></div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-hover" id="crpw_table">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CODE:

```
$.getJSON(url, jsonObject,
    function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].column_name + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].column_data + "</td>");
            $('#crpw_table').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

Comment: that's the code for your current format, where's your code for the desired format?

Comment: i don't have it for the desired format...i have just been trying to modify the existing..and i can't get it to that format.

Answer (score 2):

It's not much different

```
$.getJSON(url, jsonObject,
    function (data) {
        tr1 = $('<tr/>');
        tr2 = $('<tr/>');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr1.append("<td>" + data[i].column_name + "</td>");
            tr2.append("<td>" + data[i].column_data + "</td>");
        }
        $('#crpw_table').append(tr1);
        $('#crpw_table').append(tr2);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON(url, jsonObject,
    function (data) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].column_name + "</td>");
        }
        $('#crpw_table').append(tr);
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].column_data + "</td>");
        }
        $('#crpw_table').append(tr);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$.getJSON(url, jsonObject,
    function (data) {
        var tr1 = $('<tr/>');
        var tr2 = $('<tr/>');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            tr1.append("<td>" + data[i].column_name + "</td>");
            tr2.append("<td>" + data[i].column_data + "</td>");

    }
    $('#crpw_table').append(tr1).append(tr2);
});
```